# How write a good dql for knp paginator

Tags: database, symfony

I have this query:

```
 $data1 = $session->get('oficina');
 $data2 = $session->get('area');
 $dql = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Registro')->createQueryBuilder('l')
                -> where('l.oficina = (:data1) and l.area = (:data2)')
                -> setParameter('data1', $data1)
                -> setParameter('data2', $data2)
                -> orderBy('l.id', 'DESC')->getQuery();
```

And i got this error:
Warning: preg_split() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given

I wanna use this query with paginator knp bundle
I send the query to paginator:

```
    $list = $em->createQuery($dql); 
$paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
$pagination = $paginator->paginate(
    $list, /* query NOT result */
    $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
    5/*limit per page*/
);
```

Do you know what is the problem with the query???

Answer (score 0):

try it :

I think you have an error this line

```
-> where('l.oficina = (:data1) and l.area = (:data2)')
```

use it

```
    ->Where('l.oficina = :data1')
    ->andWhere('l.area = :data2')
    -> setParameter('data1', $data1)
    -> setParameter('data2', $data2)
```

OR

```
   $data1 = $session->get('oficina');
        $data2 = $session->get('area');
        $em    = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $dql   = "SELECT l FROM AppBundle:Registro a WHERE l.oficina = '$data1' and l.area = '$data2'";
        $list = $em->createQuery($dql);

        $paginator  = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
            $list,
            $request->query->getInt('page', 1)/*page number*/,
            5,/*limit per page*/
            array('defaultSortFieldName' => 'l.id', 'defaultSortDirection' => 'desc')
        );
```